# My navbar icon is not displaying the menu after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

After clicking the responsive drop down menu, it's supposed to display the menu list items, instead nothing happens, it just state the same.

```
 <!-- header design -->

  <header class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Portfolio</a>

    <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></i>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

css here

```
  .logo{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: default;
  }
 
  .navbar{
    margin-left: 35%;
  }

  .navbar a{
     font-size: 1.7rem;
     color: var(--text-color);
     margin-left: 4rem;
     transition: .3s;
     text-decoration: none;
  }

  .navbar a:hover,
  .navbar a.active{
     color: var(--main-color);
  }


  #menu-icon{
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: var(text);
    display: none;
  }

media query

@media (max-width:768px) {
     #menu-icon{
      display: block;
     }

     .navbar{
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 1rem 3%;
      background: var(--bg-color);
      border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0, .2);
      box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      display: none;
     }

     .navbar.active{
      display: block;
     }

     .navbar a {
      display: block; 
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin: 3rem 0;
     }
}
```

Javascript here

```
// toggle icon navbar//
Let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
Let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};



/*scroll sections active links*/

let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = documents.querySelectorAll('header nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => {
     Let top = window.scrollY;
     Let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
     Let height = sec.offsetHeight;
     Let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

     if(top => offset && top < offset + height){
         navLinks.forEach(links => {
            links.classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('header nav a[href*=' + id+ ']').classList.add('active');
         });
     };
    });

    /*sticky navbar*/
    let 
};
```

expected the menu icon to display the drop down , but instead nothing happens.

Comment: In your Javascript, you are using `Let` instead of `let`, which doesn't work. And because of that the variables are not defined and can't react to onclick.

Comment: thank you , now the click function is working , but nothing is displaying

Comment: Welcome! please read the section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to add a reproducible environment in question or jsfiddle, codepen, or a similar platform. I can't reproduce the issue right now

Comment: There's a typo in your JavaScript code. 'documents' should be 'document'.

Answer (score 1):

Put your js code in index.html in `<script></script>` block.
Issue resolved. I think it's a callback function issue in external file.

```
<script>
    let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
    let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

    menuIcon.onclick = () => {
        menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
        navbar.classList.toggle('active');
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// toggle icon navbar//
let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};



/*scroll sections active links*/

let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('header nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
    sections.forEach(sec => {
     let top = window.scrollY;
     let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
     let height = sec.offsetHeight;
     let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

     if(top => offset && top < offset + height){
         navLinks.forEach(links => {
            links.classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('header nav a[href*=' + id+ ']').classList.add('active');
         });
     };
    });

};
```

```css
 .logo{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: default;
  }
 
  .navbar{
    margin-left: 35%;
  }

  .navbar a{
     font-size: 1.7rem;
     color: var(--text-color);
     margin-left: 4rem;
     transition: .3s;
     text-decoration: none;
  }

  .navbar a:hover,
  .navbar a.active{
     color: var(--main-color);
  }


  #menu-icon{
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    color: var(text);
    display: none;
  }

@media (max-width:768px) {
     #menu-icon{
      display: block;
     }

     .navbar{
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 1rem 3%;
      background: var(--bg-color);
      border-top: .1rem solid rgba(0,0,0, .2);
      box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      display: none;
     }

     .navbar.active{
      display: block;
     }

     .navbar a {
      display: block; 
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin: 3rem 0;
     }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<!-- header design -->

  <header class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Portfolio</a>

    <i class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></i>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

You have written `Let` instead of `let` and `documents` instead of `document`,